# Multi Item Carousel in angular 6

Tags: angular, carousel

How can i achieve a multi item carousel in angular 6 without using any jquery plug in. I've looked into few carousel packages like ngx-bootstrap but they leave a hole if i want to show two at a time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52018888/bootstrap-slides-lagging-while-using-multi-item-carousel-using-angular-6/57102457#57102457