# can not using slick carousel dynamically on angular 7

Tags: angular, carousel, slick.js

when i use carousel on static data, it works fine. the code using static image carousel is below

```
         <div class="row">
              <h2 class="text-uppercase fs-20px text-strong">Category</h2>

              <div class="wrapperr">
                  <div class="carousell">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1"></div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2"></div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3"></div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4"></div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5"></div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6"></div>
                </div>
              </div>

          </div>
```

[image: it works when using static image]

but when i try to using dynamic image data, the carousel not work. the code is below

```
<div class="row">
              <h2 class="text-uppercase fs-20px text-strong">Category</h2>

              <div class="wrapperr">
                  <div class="carousell">
                    <div class="slider">
                    <div *ngFor="let category of categories">
                      <img [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(category.image == '' ||category.image == null || category.image === undefined ? globals.defaultThumbnail : category.image)">
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

          </div>
```

The .ts file code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.carousell').slick({
      slidesToShow: 2.25,
      // dots:true,
      centerMode: false,
      infinite: false,
      });
      });
```

Comment: you're using jQuery inside TS file?

Comment: @AkberIqbal yess

Comment: use <ng-container> to not add extra tags to your .html, any way, you can use others carousel in Angular and avoid JQuery, see for ng-bootstrap solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131765/customise-ng-bootrap-carousel-in-angular/57134727#57134727, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52018888/bootstrap-slides-lagging-while-using-multi-item-carousel-using-angular-6/57102457#57102457

Answer (score 1):

Please change your html like this

```
.....
<div class="carousell">
    <ng-template *ngFor="let category of categories">
        <img [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(category.image == '' ||category.image == null || category.image === undefined ? globals.defaultThumbnail : category.image)">
    </ng-template>
</div>
....
```

Comment: ng-template get me nothing :(

Comment: Do you use custom `ChangeDetector`